# But what exactly is printed when %d is used instead of %p?

Tags: c, pointers, printf, memory-address

As the code shows this random, seemly trash, number printed when %d is called is spaced 'sizeof(type)' numbers of the next element of a vector.

BUT if I convert the hexadecimal address of the first element, it does not match with the number.

So if it isn't the address represented in decimals, then what this printed number exactly is?

0x7ffcd6b154c0 == 140723910431936

Whereas the printed decimal was -693021504

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
  int x[] = {2, 5}, *ptr = &x;
  printf("%d\n", ptr);
  printf("%p\n", ptr);

  printf("\n%d %d\n", ptr, (ptr + 1));
}
```

Comment: Hint you can run in your browser: `(-693021504 >>> 0).toString(16)`. Also, calling `printf` with the wrong argument types for the arguments is a mistake (probably undefined behaviour), so don’t; you do funny things with pointers more reliably by casting first.

Answer (score 0):

It's using the D6B154C0, from the 7ffcd6b154c0 which is -693021504 as a 32 bit number.

Answer (score 0):

It's a dice-roll because you invoke *Undefined Behavior*:

> [C11 Standard - 7.21.6.1 The fprintf
>   function(p9)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9) `"If
>   a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. If
>   any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion
>   specification, the behavior is undefined."`

More likely than not what will print is the actual pointer address on system where  pointers are the same size as `int` (e.g. x86), otherwise, you will print 4-bytes out of the 8-byte pointer if you are lucky.

Answer (score 0):

The size of a typical integer is 4 bytes(range of integers being -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647) for modern compilers.
And when "%d" is used as a type specifier, it prints the address pointed by ptr as a 32-bit integer. 
But 
Since the size of ptr is typically 8 bytes the value of address that is in Hexadecimal can't be converted to Decimal completely,
Thus an inconsistency is introduced.

Understand it another way:
140723910431936 is nowhere between the range of integers and printing it with type specifier "%d"  won't provide correct result